# Strange behavior triggering event to parent component to modify list order React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, parent-child

I have a child component which renders an image from a URL. The parent component renders the list of images. I want to sort all components where the image fails to load to the end of the list, so I'm passing the onError trigger to the parent.

If I comment out the `setBad` within `throwBad` then ALL images are loaded (either the image exists or we fall back on the default).

However the result when we include `setBad` is that the children are properly highlighted in green when an image exists, and red when it doesn't, but there both red/green highlights with broken images (meaning the src isn't updated properly).

NOTE: The sorting is handled by flexbox order. Using tailwind classes and you can see it where we set `order-first` and `order-last`

```
import { useState } from "react";

const DisplayImage = ({ id, src, className, throwBad }) => {
    const [nsrc, setNsrc] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        if (src !== undefined) return setNsrc(src);
        setNsrc("/a/default/image.png");
    }, [src]);

    return <img src={nsrc} className={className} onError={(e) => {
        setNsrc("/a/default/image.png");
        throwBad(id);
    }} />;
};

const DisplayList = () => {
  const [bad, setBad] = useState({});
  const [list, setList] = useState([
    {id: 1, img: "url1"},
    {id: 2, img: "url2"},
    {id: 3, img: "url3"},
  ]);
  return (
    <div className="container mx-auto my-5 p-5 grid grid-cols-1">
        {list.map((a) => (
          <DisplayImage
            key={a._id}
            id={a.id}
            src={a.img}
            className={`h-60 cursor-pointer border-4 ${
              bad[a._id]
                ? "order-last border-red-600"
                : "order-first border-green-600"
            }`}
            throwBad={(id) => {
              if (bad[id]) return; // already done
              setBad({ ...bad, [id]: true });
            }}
          />
        ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

EDIT: Also updated to correct the mistake @Arkellys pointed out.

EDIT: Updated to point out the sorting logic pointed out by @Adam.

Comment: I'd recommend to make another component that wraps `DisplayImage` and handles the border setting logic in there if the src is bad or not. It'll remove the concept of having to keep track of which images in a list of images are bad, and only ever worry about dealing with what happens if one image is bad. In doing so, you may also expose the problem you're encountering.

Comment: `I want to sort all components where the image fails to load to the end of the list` - you haven't shown this logic at all. And your problem smells like a `key` problem anyway, so this code is very important.

Comment: I was using tailwind so you don't see the CSS maybe, but the classes `order-first` and `order-last` use flex order to handle the sorting.